# create class via input from cin fetched with operator>>

Tags: c++, oop, input, cin

My assignment I to create the following classes with the following data members / member functions.

- Computer

  - RAM (in GB).
  - Processor Speed (in GHz).
  - # of Cores
  - Hard Drive Storage Size (in GB).
  - Print (Virtual Function)
- Desktop (inherits from Computer)

  - hasMonitor
  - monitorSize (in Inches)
- Laptop (inherits from Computer)

  - screenSize
- Cluster (inherits from Computer)
- Number of computers

I should add a virtual print function and take input for each desktop/laptop I have. Can someone help me with figuring out why its not taking any input for it?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class computers{
      public:
      int ram;
      double processor_speed;
      int num_cores;
      int hd_storage;
      computers();
      };
computers::computers()
{
 ram=0;
 processor_speed=0;
 num_cores=0;
 hd_storage=0;


}


class desktop: public computers{
      public:
      bool hasMonitor;
      double monitor_size;
      desktop();
      friend istream& operator>>(istream& isObject, desktop& desk1);

      };

desktop::desktop()
{
 hasMonitor=true;
 monitor_size=0;                 

}
istream& operator>>(istream& isObject, desktop& desk1)
      {

          isObject>>desk1.hasMonitor;
          isObject>>desk1.monitor_size;
          isObject>>desk1.ram;
          isObject>>desk1.processor_speed;
          isObject>>desk1.hd_storage;
          isObject>>desk1.num_cores;
          if(desk1.hasMonitor==0)
              desk1.hasMonitor=false;

          return isObject;
      }


class laptop:public computers{
      public:
      int screen_size;
      laptop();
      friend istream& operator>>(istream& isObject,laptop& lap1);
      };
laptop::laptop()
{
screen_size=0;                

}
istream& operator>> (istream& isObject, laptop& lap1)
{
    isObject>> lap1.ram;
    isObject>> lap1.processor_speed;
    isObject>> lap1.hd_storage;
    isObject>> lap1.num_cores;
    isObject>> lap1.screen_size;
    return isObject;
}
class cluster:public computers{
      public:
      int num_of_comps;
      friend istream& operator>>(istream& isObject,cluster& clust1);
      cluster();


      };
cluster::cluster()
{
num_of_comps=0;

}

istream& operator>>(istream& isObject,cluster& clust1)
{
    isObject >> clust1.ram;
    isObject >> clust1.processor_speed;
    isObject >> clust1.hd_storage;
    isObject >> clust1.num_cores;
    isObject >> clust1.num_of_comps;
    return isObject;
}
cluster operator+(const computers& comp1, const computers& comp2)
{
    cluster mrcluster;
    mrcluster.ram = comp1.ram+comp2.ram;
    mrcluster.processor_speed = comp1.processor_speed+comp2.processor_speed;
    mrcluster.num_cores = comp1.num_cores+comp2.num_cores;
    mrcluster.hd_storage = comp1.hd_storage+comp2.hd_storage;
    return mrcluster;
}

int main()
{
    laptop laptop1;
    desktop desktop1;
    desktop desktop2;
    cluster mycluster = laptop1+desktop1+desktop2;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Is there an error? What do you see (or not see) that suggests something is wrong?

Comment: There is no error. Its supposed to give me an option to input the hasMonitor ...etc for desktop1 desktop2 laptop1 etc

Comment: Im rather new and I am not too familiar with classes and such

Answer (score 1):

You are not asking for any input in your `main` function.  `main` is your entry point for your program so anything you want done must originate there (e.g. function call to ask for input).

Comment: but what function would I call for the overloaded >>?

Comment: `cin >> laptop1;` would call the `operator>>(ostream&, laptop&)` function to fill `laptop1` with the data you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do cin>> laptop1

btw I would call your base class computer not computers